# Automatic/dynamic margin in Android layout

Tags: android

I was wondering if it's possible to set an automatic/dynamic margin (padding?) between elements in an Android layout without having to do it programmatically?

For example let's say there is a horizontal LinearLayout which is set to `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` and that contains five elements. Is there a setting that evenly shares the remaining empty space of the LinearLayout to the margins of the child elements?

See image at http://img63.imageshack.us/img63/8/margin.png

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You could use view spacers as your margin, with the layout weight set on them.

```
<LinearLayout ...>
    <View id=marginLeft android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Element1/>
    <Element2/>
    <Element3/>
    <Element4/>
    <Element5/>

    <View id=marginRight android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This should make the two views use up any remaining space in your row. Note, the above XML will not parse :)

-- Edit

Just saw the picture. To add equal spacing between each of the elements too would just be a case of adding more spacer elements between your content elements (all with the same layout weight)

Comment: Cool. How about when we want negative margins?

Comment: @George http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673503/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-negative-margins-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Yup. Only LinearLayouts support it. Tis called layout weight

Look for LinearLayout at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html

For a good intro, look [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html)

Comment: Can you please give an example of the layout XML? I thought the weight attribute gives some of the remaining space to an element. I was talking about the margins though.