# android -- hide part of linear layout off-screen to the right

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have two linear layouts inside a parent linear layout. all horizontal. I want all of `l_child` to show and part of `r_child` to show; while the rest of `r_child` will be off-screen to the right. How do I accomplish that?

```
<LinearLayout

    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l_child"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/r_child"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post a schematic of what you want to do?

Comment: Not sure I understand, but here: if you will, image each child linear layouts has three imageviews; then I want all three images of the left child to show, but only the first image of the right child to show; while the remaining two hide offscreen to the right.

Comment: by schematic I mean a little drawing showing what you want to accomplish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layout weights are only for distributing layouts to fill a view, so no overflowing can be done this way.

Assigning layout_width with density independent pixels will result in varied success for different size devices.

So I believe you would have more success adding your layouts programmatically based on the screen size.

See this post for getting the screen width:
[Get screen dimensions in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/how-to-get-screen-dimensions)

Once you have the screen width, you can assign the inner-layout dimensions by pixels (with LinearLayout.LayoutParams), calculated as percentages of the screen width.

If you want the left layout to take up 80% of the screen, use .8*screen_width for the size, and if you want the right layout to then overflow by 20% of the screen, use .4*screen_width for that size.

Answer (score 6):

Try giving the parent `LinearLayout` a negative right margin.

```
android:layout_marginRight="-50dp"
```

Other solution might be to put the parent `LinearLayout` inside a `ScrollView`, and set the widths of children layouts to the desired width. In this case, you'll be able to scroll the right layout back to the screen.

Comment: AFAIK they do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673503/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-negative-margins-in-android I'll check it really quickly just in case.

Comment: Interesting, I thought I remembered trying it before without success

Comment: It does work. Tested with TextView within a LinearLayout with layout_marginLeft="-10dp". See the screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g5arw3zm780gtyp/Screenshot_2013-06-29-01-36-34.png

Comment: Nice, I wonder if it works on older SDK versions, it would have been a couple years ago that I would have tried it.  I still think programmatically setting widths to percentages of the screen size would offer more consistency across devices in this case though.

Comment: Sure thing. By why not combine the two? You can set the negative margin dynamically to extend the canvas. See the example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qw1msodltt15jid/Screenshot_2013-06-29-01-48-17.png?m  It's two layouts with weights set to 1, but the parent has a negative left margin of -100dp. Cool stuff:) Didn't explore this stuff before.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginRight="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ViewPager, but I don't know if you can get the "bleeding canvas" effect that you're describing using that UI component.

EDIT: Maybe you can try using Gallery widget.

Is this what you're describing?

http://www.bangkokpost.com/media/content/20110915/309542.jpg