# move one specific ImageView

Tags: android, layout, if-statement, tags, imageview

```
private void movePlane() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    spielbereich = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.spielbereich);
    int nummer = 0;
    while (nummer<spielbereich.getChildCount()) {
        ImageView muecke = (ImageView) spielbereich.getChildAt(nummer);



        if (muecke.getTag() == AIRPLANE ){


        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams) muecke.getLayoutParams();
        params.leftMargin -= 10;
        muecke.setLayoutParams(params);

        nummer ++;}
        }
    }
```

Hello,
I want to just move the ImageView with the specific tag, but when I do it like this the app would crash.
In the layout there is one permanent ImageView. The others are created within the Activity. 
Can anyone help with that?

Comment: What exception do you get when the program crashes?

Comment: actually nothing...  when I start the activtiy the screen turns black and after some times it says:"doesn"t react"

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast an an ImageView to a FrameLayout.
If you want to use the margins of a FrameLayout for moving, then try wrapping each ImageView in it's own individual FrameLayout inside your spielbereich FrameLayout.

You also have no check for negative values of `params.leftMargin`.
While this is not the cause of your main problem, it could result in unexpected behavior for a frame layout. Romain Guy (core Android Dev at Google) recommends you avoid this.
Have a look at the links in the answer to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673503/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-negative-margins-in-android)

Comment: What is the code calling this method? Is it a one off call, or is it looping and the view is whizzing off to infinity?

Comment: but with the if statement everything works fine except the permanent ImageView also is moved.

Comment: Actually I wrap every ImageView in its own frameLayout: FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(muecke_breite,muecke_hoehe);
  params.leftMargin = breite;
  params.topMargin = oben;
     params.gravity= Gravity.TOP + Gravity.LEFT;
     spielbereich.addView(muecke,params);

Comment: Ok, it works. I had just to put "params.leftMargin -= 10;" inside the if statement the rest out of it.