# RatingBar doesn't appear in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, ratingbar

I Have a ListView with one RatingBar and two textviews, when I run the app in the emulator, it show correctly, but when I try to run it on my galaxy S3 the ratingbar doesn't appear in the listview, only the textviews appear.

Anyone know what I should have to do to correct it ?

ItemLista

```
    public class ItemLista {
private String nome;
private String comentario;
private float nota;

public ItemLista(String nome, String comentario, float nota) {
    super();
    this.nome = nome;
    this.comentario = comentario;
    this.nota = nota;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}
public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
public String getComentario() {
    return comentario;
}
public void setComentario(String comentario) {
    this.comentario = comentario;
}
public float getNota() {
    return nota;
}
public void setNota(float nota) {
    this.nota = nota;
}   
}
```

ComentariosAdapter

```
    public class ComentariosAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemLista> {
private final Context context;        
    private final ArrayList<ItemLista> itemsArrayList;

    public ComentariosAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ItemLista> itemsArrayList) {

    super(context, R.layout.item_lista_comentarios, itemsArrayList);

    this.context = context;
    this.itemsArrayList = itemsArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // 1. Create inflater 
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // 2. Get rowView from inflater
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_lista_comentarios, parent, false);

    // 3. Get the two text view from the rowView
    TextView nameView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtUsuario);
    TextView comentarioView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtComentario);
    RatingBar rankView = (RatingBar) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rankSmall);

    // 4. Set the text for textView 
    nameView.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getNome());
    comentarioView.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getComentario());
    rankView.setRating(itemsArrayList.get(position).getNota());
    rankView.setIsIndicator(true);

    // 5. return rowView
    return rowView;
    }
    }
```

TabDetalhes

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_detalhes, container, false);

    RatingBar rank = (RatingBar) V.findViewById(R.id.rank);
    rank.setRating((float) 3.5);
    rank.setIsIndicator(true);

    ComentariosAdapter adapter = new ComentariosAdapter(V.getContext(), dados());

    ListView lista = (ListView) V.findViewById(R.id.listaComentarios);

    lista.setAdapter(adapter);             
    return V;
    }

private ArrayList<ItemLista> dados(){
    ArrayList<ItemLista> items = new ArrayList<ItemLista>();
    items.add(new ItemLista("Lucas Freitas","Lugar legal, ambiente confortavel", 4.5f));
    items.add(new ItemLista("Eduardo Bonight","Cara, comi tanto que pediram pra eu sair D:", 3.5f));
    items.add(new ItemLista("Guilherme Garcia","O que eu to fazendo aqui ? o.O", 2.5f));
    items.add(new ItemLista("Caique Sampaio","Mano...eu tava upando ¬¬", 2.5f));

    return items;
    }
    }
```

item_lista_comentario.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rankSmall"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
        android:scaleX="0.4"
        android:scaleY="0.4"
        style="@style/rankRating" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtUsuario"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#565656"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"  />

</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtComentario"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#565656"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="15sp"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please provide more detail: xml layout files, relevant code, &c.

Comment: You need provide at least code that so that people can help, you have provided us with nothing to go on.

Comment: Sorry about that, I put the code now.

Comment: Do the emulator and physical device have the same Android version? Can you try running the app on the emulator with some other Android version, for example the same one as the Samsung Galaxy S3?

Comment: Are both screens the same size?

Comment: I did other tests, and when I run the emu on API 16 ( 4.1.2 ) The listview doesn't show the ratingbar, on API 18 ( 4.3 ) it show up correctly, I just can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

What is the size of the `RatingBar`? You give it negative margins `-60dp` and `-5dp`, so my guess is your `RatingBar` is moved out of the visible area.

Guess based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673503/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-negative-margins-in-android).

Comment: But, why it show up correctly in the emulator and not in the cell phone ?

I Will try to give it positive margins.