# Android XML ImageView marginLeft property

Tags: android, xml, syntax-error

I need to set the image closer then the element in its left. The only way to do that is by editing the image taking all the margins off? what if i need it even closer?

Does the marginLeft accept a negative value?

This is how the ImageView is at xml file:

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/lineOneImageView"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="false"
android:layout_marginLeft="-6"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/productNameTextView"
android:contentDescription="@string/text_placeholder"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:src="@drawable/img_i_black_normal" />
```

This is the error at this line: android:layout_marginLeft="-6"

```
Error: Integer types not allowed (at 'layout_marginLeft' with value '-6').
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the dp as an extension:

```
android:layout_marginLeft="-6dp"
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error because you missed the dimension unit **dp**. Android accepts negative margins if the layout is relative or linearlayout. See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673503/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-negative-margins-in-android).