# Android listview to overlay another view

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a view which contains a top view (it's a mapview but it's not implemented yet) and a listview below it.

What I'm trying to do is to make the top of listview to be overlay the bottom of the top view a little bit. Here is something similar to what I'm trying to achieve :

[image]

**(without the tab headers and the image will be the mapview)**

I'm not sure how I can achieve that, here is what I have so far:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark">

    </View>

    <com.hmm.widgets.CustomListView
        android:id="@+id/runners_list"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray">

    </com.hmm.widgets.CustomListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried negative margin which didn't work. I'm not sure how can I achieve something similar. Should I be using FrameLayout?

Comment: I added an alternative solution with RelativeLayout.

Comment: how did you get the padding at the top of that listview to show the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LinearLayout` in your case and design the layout like this. This is a trick of setting a negative `layout_marginTop` to your custom `ListView`

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark">

    </View>

    <com.hmm.widgets.CustomListView
        android:id="@+id/runners_list"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray">

    </com.hmm.widgets.CustomListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That's strange. I did the same thing but the only difference was that my view and lisview had weight. Maybe that was the reason. I will try this and will let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Complementing [Reaz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35682024/913286), you can do it with `RelativeLayout` too without using negative margins (which are a bit [controversial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673503/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-negative-margins-in-android)).

Note the last four attributes in the `CustomListView`: you constraint the height with `alignParent*`, set a dummy height which will be discarded, and offset the view from the top with a margin. The "negative offset" will be `250dp - 200dp = 50 dp`.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark">

    </View>

    <com.hmm.widgets.CustomListView
        android:id="@+id/runners_list"    
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"

        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </com.hmm.widgets.CustomListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```