# Reduce Spacing between Tiles

Tags: android, android-cardview

I'm using this awesome library [twoway-view](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view) and I got my desired layout.

[image]

However, I wanted to reduce the space between each tiles. Right now as you can see there are plenty of white space between each tile.

Anyone who can guide?

Comment: post your XML code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `android:layout_margin` attribute for the xml of your item in list.

Here is [demo](http://android4beginners.com/2013/07/lesson-2-2-how-to-use-margins-and-paddings-in-android-layout/). Read more from docs on layout margins and padding for alignment related issues.

Comment: Thanks man, it was all about margins and I was ignoring that. Anyways I've checked the link you shared, my question is can we give negative layout margins? I mean is it suitable for variety of mobile screens??

Comment: Always try to use "dp" when playing with margins. It will work same across all screens. Read about it from developer documents. For negative margins read this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/10673572/3260244