# Avoid side padding from particular child item of LazyColumn in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-layout

I want to removed side padding of particular child item in `LazyColum`. I solved this problem in xml with the help of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69887412/8266651). I have same scenario in the jetpack compose. I am using BOM versions of `compose_bom = "2022.11.00"` with **Material 3**.

```
    Card(shape = RoundedCornerShape(6.dp),) {
        Column(modifier.background(Color.White)) {
            LazyColumn(
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(all =16.dp),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
            ) {
                item {
                    Text(
                        text = "Device Header",
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 10.dp),
                        style = headerTextStyle
                    )
                }

                item {
                    Divider() // remove padding from side in here
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Actual Output**

[image]

**Expected Output**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Compose you can't use a **negative padding** in the children to reduce the padding applied by the parent container. You can use **`offset`** modifer with a negative value but it will shift the `Divider` on the left side.

You can use a **`layout`** modifier to apply an horizontal offset increasing the width.

Something like:

```
LazyColumn(
    Modifier.background(Yellow),
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(all = 16.dp),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
) {
    //...

    item {
        val sidePadding = (-8).dp

 
        Divider(modifier = Modifier
            .layout { measurable, constraints ->
                // Measure the composable adding the side padding*2 (left+right)
                val placeable =
                    measurable.measure(constraints.offset(horizontal = -sidePadding.roundToPx() * 2))

                //increase the width adding the side padding*2
                layout(
                    placeable.width + sidePadding.roundToPx() * 2,
                    placeable.height
                ) {
                    // Where the composable gets placed
                    placeable.place(+sidePadding.roundToPx(), 0)
                }

            }
        )          
        
    }
}
```

Here you can find the output with a `Divider()` without modifier, and the `Divider` with the `layout` modifier.

[image]

Comment: how can I fix in the right side? Can you please explain me in detail what we are doing in `layout` ?

Comment: @VivekModi It depends on what you want to achieve in the right side. The layout modifier measures the composable applying a horizontal offset (leftPadding) and then places the content increasing the width of +leftPadding.roundToPx().  Change the width according to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes I tried to increase width and it only increase left side and I want same thing on right side. So If I create rightPadding where should the value goes?

Comment: @VivekModi I've updated the answer, increasing the divider with the same width on both side.