# why can't I take any object outside the screen

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I could once do so, but I was forced to reinstall the android studio and after the update did a new project, and I needed to take a little object behind the screen, but I could not why ??
[image]

I've already googled and looked at similar queries on stack overflow , but to no avail, always the same option "margin(side) = "-quantity dp""

Comment: i think it has to do with the android studio update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in some answers under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673503/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-negative-margins-in-android), firstly - **using negative margin values is a bad practice** and you should avoid this approach and secondly, you can set negative values to `translation` with the same result

Comment: can you please give an example ??

Comment: As you can see on [this](https://ibb.co/2gcHtKd) screenshot ([newest Android studio version](https://ibb.co/jTH6cw3)), setting ```translationX```  to negative value will move the view off the screen.